# iOS Sort Array of Specific Strings

Tags: ios, arrays, sorting

I have an array of strings like such:

```
NSArray *unsortedArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"MailIn", @"Branch", @"eSign", @"RDC", nil];
```

I receive this array and it is not gauranteed that all 4 strings will be present. It could have all 4, or only 1.

I need to sort the array in this exact order all the time.. [eSign, RDC, Branch, MailIn]. Keep in mind that there is a chance where one or more of these may not be present. How do I achieve this?? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would build a new array, using the exemplar array as a template:

```
NSArray *exemplarArray = @[ @"eSign", @"RDC", @"Branch", @"MailIn" ];
NSArray *unsorted = @[ @"MailIn", @"Branch", @"eSign", @"RDC" ];

NSMutableArray *sorted = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSString *string in exemplarArray) {
    if ([unsorted containsObject:string]) {
        [sorted addObject:string];
    }
}
NSLog(@"%@", sorted);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you really want a sort then here is a way to do that.  But for only 4 strings I'd likely just unroll @Zev Eisenberg's loop and build it up in code.

```
NSDictionary* indexes = @{ @"eSign" : @0, @"RDC" : @1, @"Branch" : @2, @"MailIn" : @3 };
NSArray* sorted = [unsorted sortedArrayUsingComparator: ^NSComparisonResult(NSString* s1, NSString* s2) {

    return [indexes[s1] compare: indexes[s2]];
}];
```

Comment: I like that this is O(n) instead of O(n * m) (or thereabouts), so it will scale better with a larger data set. I would still build the dictionary out of an array, though, so you don't have to type the number for each entry by hand: `for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < exemplar.count; i++) { indexes[@(i)] = exemplar[i]; }`.